# Convert KNN train from Opencv 3 to 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I am reading a tutorial for training KNN using Opencv. The code is written for Opencv 3 but I need to use it in Opencv 2. The original training is:

```
cv2.ml.KNearest_create().train(npaFlattenedImages, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, npaClassifications)
```

I tried using this:

```
cv2.KNearest().train(npaFlattenedImages, cv2.CV_ROW_SAMPLE, npaClassifications)
```

but the error is:

`Unsupported index array data type (it should be 8uC1, 8sC1 or 32sC1) in function cvPreprocessIndexArray`

The full code is here:
https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Python/blob/master/TrainAndTest.py

Comment: With the command you propose I have `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KNearest'`

Comment: Please give the relevant stacktrace, too, not just the error message.

Comment: Are you using Python and Opencv 2? I am getting the same error. Check out this link for the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html

Comment: Steven, Stack Overflow etiquette in this case would have been to recognize my answer (first) or ivan_pozdeev's (more detail), but Rueen1963's answer is basically a copy.

Comment: What does npa prefix for variable name stand for? Non Performing Assets (NPA) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the changes that appear to have made the [full code](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Python/blob/master/TrainAndTest.py) work for me for OpenCV 2.4.13:

```
60c60
<     kNearest = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()                   # instantiate KNN object
---
>     kNearest = cv2.KNearest()                   # instantiate KNN object
62c62
<     kNearest.train(npaFlattenedImages, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, npaClassifications)
---
>     kNearest.train(npaFlattenedImages, npaClassifications)
85c85
<     imgContours, npaContours, npaHierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThreshCopy,             # input image, make sure to use a copy since the function will modify this image in the course of finding contours
---
>     npaContours, npaHierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThreshCopy,             # input image, make sure to use a copy since the function will modify this image in the course of finding contours
125c125
<         retval, npaResults, neigh_resp, dists = kNearest.findNearest(npaROIResized, k = 1)     # call KNN function find_nearest
---
>         retval, npaResults, neigh_resp, dists = kNearest.find_nearest(npaROIResized, k = 1)     # call KNN function find_nearest
```

Answer (score 0):

- Unlike the generic [`CvStatModel::train()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#bool%20CvStatModel::train%28const%20Mat&%20train_data,%20[int%20tflag,]%20...,%20const%20Mat&%20responses,%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20var_idx,]%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20sample_idx,]%20...%20[const%20Mat&%20var_type,]%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20missing_mask,]%20%3Cmisc_training_alg_params%3E%20...%29), [`cv2.KNearest.train()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html?highlight=cv_row_sample#cv2.KNearest.train) doesn't have the 2nd optional argument `int tflag`, and the docs say: "Only `CV_ROW_SAMPLE` data layout is supported".

  - The error message (btw the cryptic mnemonics are [OpenCV data types](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#datatype)) was thus caused by the function trying to use `npaClassifications` as the next argument, `sampleIdx`.

Further errors after fixing this:

- [`cv2.findCountours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours) only returns 2 values: `→ contours, hierarchy` (you don't need the 3rd one, `imgContours`, anyway).
- `KNearest.findNearest()` was [`KNearest.find_nearest()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html?highlight=find%20nearest#cv2.KNearest.find_nearest).

And the result now:

[image: result]

[Ulrich Stern already did me a favor to provide a raw diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684278/648265).