# too many values to unpack calling cv2.findContours

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am a python beginner . I was trying to run this code :

```
#applying closing function 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(th3, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

#finding_contours 
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

when I summon the mask.py I got this ValueError :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mask.py", line 22, in <module>
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: have you tried removing the parentheses?  cnts, heir = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? I assume you're using 3.x, but writing code meant for the 2.x branch. There were some API changes -- one of those being that `findContours` returns 3, instead of the original 2 values. Read the documentation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598724/convert-knn-train-from-opencv-3-to-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compatibility issue with contourArea in openCV 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475125/compatibility-issue-with-contourarea-in-opencv-3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that you're using OpenCV version 3.x, while writing code intended for the 2.x branch. There were some API changes between those two branches. Since you're using Python, you have a handy help available -- make sure to use it, along with the documentation.

OpenCV 2.x:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours in module cv2:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy
```

OpenCV 3.x:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

This means that in your script the correct way to call `findContours` when using OpenCV 3.x would be something like

```
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

---

**UPDATE (Dec 2018)**

In OpenCV 4.x, [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns 2 values only.

```
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy
    .   @brief Finds contours in a binary image.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cv2.findContours()` irrespective of the version with following code snippet:

```
import cv2 as cv
version = cv.__version__
version = version[0]

if version == '4' or version == '2':
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
elif version == '3':
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

OpenCV `2.x` and `4.x` returns 2 variables, while `3.x` return 3 variables

Comment: I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'` Added another `elif` instead.