# getting a value error using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

While finding contours I am getting a value error as "too many values to unpack"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/check5.py", line 8, in <module>
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/32248/open-cv-30-findcontours-return-too-many-value-to-unpack/

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) - `... in the output, we got three arrays, first is the image, second is our contours, and one more output which we named as hierarchy ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [too many values to unpack calling cv2.findContours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960257/too-many-values-to-unpack-calling-cv2-findcontours)

Answer (score 0):

The function 'cv2.findContours' returns 3 values.
Change your code.

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```