# Identify the orientation of page

Tags: python, opencv, text, ocr, document-layout-analysis

[Image of portrait page viewed horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Se4O.jpg)

Hello suppose we have this photo of a page(or many pages)  ,
you rotate if 90,180 degree  anticlockwise

I want to write code in order to detect the position of the page number to find out the orientation of the page and  rotate the photo to have the right orientation. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please add any code attempt that you have written so far to your question.

Comment: Also search.. there's other SO questions on this subject on the site, have you tried any of the solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010660/detect-image-orientation-angle-based-on-text-direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854176/is-there-a-way-i-can-detect-the-image-orientation-and-rotate-the-image-to-the-ri https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-determine-the-orientation-of-an-object-using-opencv/ (These are only a few)

Comment: Try each of the four 90 degree rotations and see which one pytesseract will read

Comment: Hello  
Rachel Gallen  ,thank you for your suggetions. Yes I alrady seen those answers,I think those solutions works if the document is a scaned photo ,but with my files dosen't work because tessract can something if the page is up-side down .Anway right now I don't find my files because ,it's been long time  since the first time I work to some this problem.