# Python ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, pycharm, iterable-unpacking, opencover

I am getting python for,

### Code

```
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
```

### Error (2nd line)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hissain/PycharmProjects/hello/hello.py", line 17, in <module>
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

**How to resolve it?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to find contours -> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2), this appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164630/want-to-find-contours-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `cv2.findContours` [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), the function return only 2 values. You try to unpack 3.

Remove the first `_` (unwanted value) from the second line to match the signature from the documentation.

```
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
```

---

Generally speaking, when you get this Python error message:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected **x** got **y**)

Search where you try to unpack `y` elements, and try to fix it by unpacking `x` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the OpenCV reference:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours

findCounters returns (contours, hierarchy), so your second lines should be:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```