# value error: not enough value to unpack in python

Tags: python

I'm using *Learning Python the Hard Way*. In the process of my learning I came across this error. Though I have been trying to debug since yesterday, I couldn't.
This is my code:

```py
import sys
from sys import argv

script, first, second = argv
print('the script is called:', script)
print('the first variable is:', first)
print('the second vriable is:', second)
print('the third variable is:', third)
```

Comment: how did you try debugging this? what (and how many) arguments are you passing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to find contours -> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2), this appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164630/want-to-find-contours-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-go)

Comment: Where is `third` supposed to have come from?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means you're trying to deconstruct an iterable (list, tuple) into more values than there are in the actual list. If you were to run

```py
print(argv, len(argv))
```

You might see that you don't have three variables in `argv`.

`argv` shows the parameters you provided while running a script. So for example, if I ran:

```py
python test_args.py
```

I would only receive: `['test_args.py']` as my `argv` variable. If I tried providing more parameters, like:

```py
python test_args.py a b
```

Then my argv would look like: `['test_args.py', 'a', 'b']`. Your code is completely dependent on how many parameters are passed when you are *running* it, so mess around with that as well to get a better sense of what is going on.

Comment: oh nice just got a headway now thanks I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are executing the script in this format

> python script.py 10 20

The problem is that you are using an extra variable `third` which is not initialized.
If you really want 3 arguments, then you have to pass three values at execution time as follows.

> python script.py 10 20 30

Then change the code as follows.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
print('the script is called:', script)
print('the first variable is:', first)
print('the second vriable is:', second)
print('the third variable is:', third)
```

Thank you