# Fast and Robust Image Stitching Algorithm for many images in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I have a stationary camera which takes photos rapidly of the continuosly moving product but in a fixed position just of the same angle (translation perspective). I need to stitch all images into a panoramic picture. I've tried by using the class Stitcher. It worked, but it took a long time to compute.
I also tried to use another method by using the SIFT detector, FNNbasedMatcher, finding Homography and then warping the images. This method works fine if I only use two images. For multiple images it still doesn't stitch them properly. Does anyone know the best and fastest image stitching algorithm for this case?

This is my code which uses the Stitcher class.

```
import time
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import sys

def main():
    # read input images
    imgs = []
    path = 'pics_rotated/'
    i = 0
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        images = [f for f in files]
        print(images)
        for i in range(0,len(images)):
            curImg = cv2.imread(path + images[i])
            imgs.append(curImg)

    stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(mode= 0)
    status ,result = stitcher.stitch(imgs)
    if status != cv2.Stitcher_OK:
        print("Can't stitch images, error code = %d" % status)
        sys.exit(-1)
    cv2.imwrite("imagesout/output.jpg", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time()
    print("Time --->>>>>", end - start)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()enter code here
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem!

Comment: I recently published the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) package and a indepth [tutorial](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md) for the stitching workflow!

Answer (score 25):

## Briefing

Although [OpenCV `Stitcher` class](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html) provides lots of methods and options to perform stitching, I find it hard to use it because of the complexity.
Therefore, I will try to provide the minimum and fastest way to perform stitching.
In case you are wondering more sophisticated approachs such as exposure compensation, I highly recommend looking at [the detailed sample code](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dd8/samples_2cpp_2stitching_detailed_8cpp-example.html).
As a side note, I will be grateful if someone can convert the following functions to use Stitcher class.

## Introduction

In order to combine multiple images into the same perspective, the following operations are needed:

- Detect and match features.
- Compute homography (perspective transform between frames).
- Warp one image onto the other perspective.
- Combine the base and warped images while keeping track of the shift in origin.
- Given the combination pattern, stitch multiple images.

## Feature detection and matching

[What are features?](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d54/tutorial_py_features_meaning.html)
They are distinguishable parts, like corners of a square, that are preserved across images.
There are different algorithms proposed for obtaining these characteristic points, like Harris, ORB, SIFT, SURF, etc.
See [`cv::Feature2d`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html) for the full list.
I will use SIFT because it is accurate and sufficiently fast.

A feature consists of a [KeyPoint](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html), which is the location in the image, and a descriptor, which is a set of numbers (e.g. a 128-D vector) that represents the properties of the feature.

After finding distinct points in images, we need to match the corresponding point pairs.
See [`cv::DescriptionMatcher`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html).
I will use Flann-based descriptor matcher.

---

First, we initialize the descriptor and matcher classes.

```
descriptor = cv.SIFT.create()
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher.create(cv.DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED)
```

Then, we find the features in each image.

```
(kps, desc) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, mask=None)
```

Now we find the corresponding point pairs.

```
if (desc1 is not None and desc2 is not None and len(desc1) >=2 and len(desc2) >= 2):
    rawMatch = matcher->knnMatch(desc2, desc1, k=2)
matches = []
# ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
ratio = 0.75
for m in rawMatch:
    if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
        matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))
```

## Homography computation

Homography is the perspective transformation from one view to another.
The parallel lines in one view may not be parallel in another, like a road to sunset.
We need to have at least 4 corresponding point pairs.
The more means redundant data that have to be decomposed or eliminated.

Homography matrix that transforms the point in the initial view to its warped position.
It is a 3x3 matrix that is computed by [Direct Linear Transform algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation).
There are 8 DoF and the last element in the matrix is 1.

```
[pt2] = H * [pt1]
```

---

Now that we have corresponding point matches, we compute the homography.
The method we use to handle redundant data is RANSAC, which randomly selects 4 point pairs and uses the best fitting result.
See [`cv::findHomography`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) for more options.

```
if len(matches) > 4:
    (H, status) = cv.findHomography(pts1, pts2, cv.RANSAC)
```

## Warping to perspective

By computing homography, we know which point in the source image corresponds to which point in the destination image.
**In order not to lose information from the source image, we need to pad the destination image by the amount that the transformed point falls to negative regions.**
At the same time, we need to keep track of the shift amount of the origin for stitching multiple images.

### Auxilary functions

```py
# find the ROI of a transformation result
def warpRect(rect, H):
    x, y, w, h = rect
    corners = [[x, y], [x, y + h - 1], [x + w - 1, y], [x + w - 1, y + h - 1]]
    extremum = cv.transform(corners, H)
    minx, miny = np.min(extremum[:,0]), np.min(extremum[:,1])
    maxx, maxy = np.max(extremum[:,0]), np.max(extremum[:,1])
    xo = int(np.floor(minx))
    yo = int(np.floor(miny))
    wo = int(np.ceil(maxx - minx))
    ho = int(np.ceil(maxy - miny))
    outrect = (xo, yo, wo, ho)
    return outrect
```

```py
# homography matrix is translated to fit in the screen
def coverH(rect, H):
    # obtain bounding box of the result
    x, y, _, _ = warpRect(rect, H)
    # shift amount to the first quadrant
    xpos = int(-x if x < 0 else 0)
    ypos = int(-y if y < 0 else 0)
    # correct the homography matrix so that no point is thrown out
    T = np.array([[1, 0, xpos], [0, 1, ypos], [0, 0, 1]])
    H_corr = T.dot(H)
    return (H_corr, (xpos, ypos))
```

```py
# pad image to cover ROI, return the shift amount of origin
def addBorder(img, rect):
    x, y, w, h = rect
    tl = (x, y)    
    br = (x + w, y + h)
    top = int(-tl[1] if tl[1] < 0 else 0)
    bottom = int(br[1] - img.shape[0] if br[1] > img.shape[0] else 0)
    left = int(-tl[0] if tl[0] < 0 else 0)
    right = int(br[0] - img.shape[1] if br[0] > img.shape[1] else 0)
    img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])
    orig = (left, top)
    return img, orig
```

```py
def size2rect(size):
    return (0, 0, size[1], size[0])
```

### Warping function

```py
def warpImage(img, H):
    # tweak the homography matrix to move the result to the first quadrant
    H_cover, pos = coverH(size2rect(img.shape), H)
    # find the bounding box of the output
    x, y, w, h = warpRect(size2rect(img.shape), H_cover)
    width, height = x + w, y + h
    # warp the image using the corrected homography matrix
    warped = cv.warpPerspective(img, H_corr, (width, height))
    # make the external boundary solid black, useful for masking
    warped = np.ascontiguousarray(warped, dtype=np.uint8)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(warped, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    _, bw = cv.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806272/12447766
    major = cv.__version__.split('.')[0]
    if major == '3':
        _, cnts, _ = cv.findContours(bw, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    else:
        cnts, _ = cv.findContours(bw, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    warped = cv.drawContours(warped, cnts, 0, [0, 0, 0], lineType=cv.LINE_4)
    return (warped, pos)
```

## Combining warped and destination images

This is the step where image enhancement such as exposure compensation becomes involved.
In order to keep things simple, we will use mean value blending.
The easiest solution would be overriding the existing data in the destination image but averaging operation is not a burden for us.

```py
# only the non-zero pixels are weighted to the average
def mean_blend(img1, img2):
    assert(img1.shape == img2.shape)
    locs1 = np.where(cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) != 0)
    blended1 = np.copy(img2)
    blended1[locs1[0], locs1[1]] = img1[locs1[0], locs1[1]]
    locs2 = np.where(cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) != 0)
    blended2 = np.copy(img1)
    blended2[locs2[0], locs2[1]] = img2[locs2[0], locs2[1]]
    blended = cv.addWeighted(blended1, 0.5, blended2, 0.5, 0)
    return blended
```

```py
def warpPano(prevPano, img, H, orig):
    # correct homography matrix
    T = np.array([[1, 0, -orig[0]], [0, 1, -orig[1]], [0, 0, 1]])
    H_corr = H.dot(T)
    # warp the image and obtain shift amount of origin
    result, pos = warpImage(prevPano, H_corr)
    xpos, ypos = pos
    # zero pad the result
    rect = (xpos, ypos, img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
    result, _ = addBorder(result, rect)
    # mean value blending
    idx = np.s_[ypos : ypos + img.shape[0], xpos : xpos + img.shape[1]]
    result[idx] = mean_blend(result[idx], img)
    # crop extra paddings
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
    result = result[y : y + h, x : x + w]
    # return the resulting image with shift amount
    return (result, (xpos - x, ypos - y))
```

## Stitching multiple images given combination pattern

```py
# base image is the last image in each iteration
def blend_multiple_images(images, homographies):
    N = len(images)
    assert(N >= 2)
    assert(len(homographies) == N - 1)
    pano = np.copy(images[0])
    pos = (0, 0)
    for i in range(N - 1):
        img = images[i + 1]
        # get homography matrix
        H = homographies[i]
        # warp pano onto image
        pano, pos = warpPano(pano, img, H, pos)
    return (pano, pos)
```

The method above warps the previously combined image, called pano, onto the next image subsequently.
A pattern, however, may have conjunction points for the best stitching view.

For example

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The best pattern to combine these images is

```
1 -> 2 <- 3
     |
     V
4 -> 5 <- 6
```

Therefore, we need one last function to combine `1 & 2` with `2 & 3`, or `1235` with `456` at node `5`.

```py
from operator import sub

# no warping here, useful for combining two different stitched images
# the image at given origin coordinates must be the same
def patchPano(img1, img2, orig1=(0,0), orig2=(0,0)):
    # bottom right points
    br1 = (img1.shape[1] - 1, img1.shape[0] - 1)
    br2 = (img2.shape[1] - 1, img2.shape[0] - 1)
    # distance from orig to br
    diag2 = tuple(map(sub, br2, orig2))
    # possible pano corner coordinates based on img1
    extremum = np.array([(0, 0), br1,
                tuple(map(sum, zip(orig1, diag2))),
                tuple(map(sub, orig1, orig2))])
    bb = cv.boundingRect(extremum)
    # patch img1 to img2
    pano, shift = addBorder(img1, bb)
    orig = tuple(map(sum, zip(orig1, shift)))
    idx = np.s_[orig[1] : orig[1] + img2.shape[0] - orig2[1],
                orig[0] : orig[0] + img2.shape[1] - orig2[0]]
    subImg = img2[orig2[1] : img2.shape[0], orig2[0] : img2.shape[1]]
    pano[idx] = mean_blend(pano[idx], subImg)
    return (pano, orig)
```

---

For a quick demo, you can run [the Python code](https://github.com/burak-yildizoz/CMPE537/blob/main/Assignment%202/A%232_Homography_and_Image_Stitching.py) in GitHub.
If you want to use the above methods in C++, you can have a look at [Stitch library](https://github.com/burak-yildizoz/OpenCV-Projects/tree/master/Stitch).
Any PR or edit to this post is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the last step that @Burak gave, this is the way I used as I had the number of images for each of the rows (chunks), the multiStitching being nothing but a function to stitch images horizontally:

```
def stitchingImagesHV(img_list, size):
    """
    As our multi stitching algorithm works on the horizontal line, we will hack
    it to use also the vertical stitching by rotating each row "stitch_img" and
    apply the same technique, and after that, the final result is rotated back to the
    original direction.
    """
    # Generate row chunks of "size" length from image list
    chunks = [img_list[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(img_list), size)]

    list_rotated_images = []

    for i in range(len(chunks)):
        stitch_img = multiStitching(chunks[i])
        stitch_img_rotated = cv2.rotate(stitch_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
        list_rotated_images.append(stitch_img_rotated.astype('uint8'))

    stitch_img2 = multiStitching(list_rotated_images)

    return cv2.rotate(stitch_img2, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```