# Image Stitching warsPerspective size issue

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch two images. tech stack is opecv c++ on vs 2017.

The image that I had considered are:

image1 of code : [image]

and

image2 of code: [image]

I have found the homoography matrix using this code. I have considered image1 and image2 as given above.

```
    int minHessian = 400;
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(minHessian);
    vector< KeyPoint > keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
    detector->detect(gray_image1, keypoints_object);
    detector->detect(gray_image2, keypoints_scene);

    
    Mat img_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints(gray_image1, keypoints_object, img_keypoints);
    imshow("SURF Keypoints", img_keypoints);

    Mat img_keypoints1;
    drawKeypoints(gray_image2, keypoints_scene, img_keypoints1);
    imshow("SURF Keypoints1", img_keypoints1);
    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
    detector->compute(gray_image1, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
    detector->compute(gray_image2, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher

    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(DescriptorMatcher::FLANNBASED);
    vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher->match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);


    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints 
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist: %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist: %f \n", min_dist);


    //-- Use only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    vector< DMatch > good_matches;
    Mat result, H;
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(gray_image1, keypoints_object, gray_image2, keypoints_scene, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1),
        Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);
    std::vector< Point2f > obj;
    std::vector< Point2f > scene;
    cout << "Good Matches detected" << good_matches.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }


    // Find the Homography Matrix for img 1 and img2
    H = findHomography(obj, scene, RANSAC);
```

The next step would be to warp these. I used perspectivetransform function to find the corner of image1 on the stitched image. I had considered this as the number of columns to be used in the `Mat result`.This is the code I wrote ->

```
    vector<Point2f> imageCorners(4);
    imageCorners[0] = Point(0, 0);
    imageCorners[1] = Point(image1.cols, 0);
    imageCorners[2] = Point(image1.cols, image1.rows);
    imageCorners[3] = Point(0, image1.rows);
    vector<Point2f> projectedCorners(4);
    perspectiveTransform(imageCorners, projectedCorners, H);
    Mat result;
    warpPerspective(image1, result, H, Size(projectedCorners[2].x, image1.rows));
    Mat half(result, Rect(0, 0, image2.cols, image2.rows));
    image2.copyTo(half);
    imshow("result", result);
```

I am getting a stitched output of these images. But the issue is with the size of the image. I was doing a comparison by combining the two original images manually with the result of the above code. The size of the result from code is more. What should I do to make it of perfect size? The ideal size should be `image1.cols + image2.cols - overlapping length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
warpPerspective(image1, result, H, Size(projectedCorners[2].x, image1.rows));
```

This line seems problematic.
You should choose the extremum points for the size.

```
Rect rec = boundingRect(projectedCorners);
warpPerspective(image1, result, H, rec.size());
```

But you will lose the parts if `rec.tl()` falls to negative axes, so you should shift the homography matrix to fall in the first quadrant.
See **Warping to perspective** section of my answer to [Fast and Robust Image Stitching Algorithm for many images in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67595337/12447766).