# Image Stitching in a large scale

Tags: python, gis, image-stitching

I am working on a project to capture small images of an entire stretch of a 2 km road and then
stitch all the images together based on an image stitching algorithm(using key point matching).
I tried using the **opencv Stitcher** class. It seems to work for small number of images. But for large amount of images, example **sitching 10000 images** together into one image, it just runs out my RAM or takes forever. Is this the only approach or is there any simpler and faster solution for this?

Would be helpful if someone gives a workable solution or approach.

Comment: Hey, this might be a use case for the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) package. It's based on the OpenCV library, but has lot's more options. For you, the [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md) might be a good place to start to grasp where the bottlenecks are in your stitching process. DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of this package. I come from the GIS field. So maybe together we'll find a sollution.

Comment: Hey @LukasWeber I already had a look into your stitching package before. It seemed interesting. I will try going through the notebook and figure out my bottleneck. Before that I want to confirm. Is it practically possible to stitch large amount of images (100000 images) together into one image?

Comment: Depends on what you know about the Images. If you know that some Images have spatial adjascency you probably should split them in subsets, and later stitch the stitching result of the subsets. I think youll run in some memory issues If not

Comment: @NitishMagendran I'm searching for the same thing, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @NitishMagendran I'm searching for the same thing.  I wrote something in OpenCV that works but needs improvement.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best module but, as per I know for big images

```
bigstitcher
```

That used in python is handy tool.

Because I’ve seen it successfully used for sets of images that are larger than 5 x 50GB images.

SO this may be helpful for you

https://imagej.net/plugins/bigstitcher/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But is bigstitcher is available with python? It looks like a separate software in which we can do image stitching. Is there a way to import **bigstitcher** in python and work?

Comment: If you stick with python, then OpenCV is only one but there are many ways you can improve your code and run the same data in OpenCV with EZ. Here is a link for reference that give you a basic idea:[Code_link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67595337/10937025)