# How to fix the Opencv ValueError in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('good.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

**Error**

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [too many values to unpack calling cv2.findContours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960257/too-many-values-to-unpack-calling-cv2-findcontours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your last line. To better understand it, here's a quote taken from [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

> See, there are three arguments in `cv2.findContours()` function, first one is source image, second is contour retrieval mode, third is contour approximation method. **And it outputs the contours and hierarchy**. Contours is a Python list of all the contours in the image. Each individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of the object.

So clearly `cv2.findContours()` only return two arguments (not 3). To fix it just change the last line to:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```